# Crop and save image using jquery in rails app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to crop an uploaded image and save the cropped image in the database in my application. I need to do this using jquery. But the problem is I do not have any model in my application. I have to submit everything using SugarCRM API's. So the railscast wasn't of much help. Can anyone help me with this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking into [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)? It's a command line software suite to do just what you want. Have jQuery send you the dimensions of the image and the dimensions of what it should be cropped to, and then invoke imagemagick on your server to convert your image to the proper dimensions. Will this work for you?